# SharePoint Wiki Table of Contents

Tags: 2013, wiki, content

Is there any syntax that when wrapped around content, automatically builds a table of contents towards the top of the wiki, similarly to how the Media Wiki works? 
I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I updated my Add navigation table to wiki page solution to support multiple levels and SharePoint 2013.

The new solution is a configurable jquery plugin and is documented in the blog post [Revised: Table of Contents for Wiki Pages](http://www.n8d.at/blog/revised-table-of-contents-for-wiki-pages/)

Answer (score 4):

There is no OOTB capability in SP 2013 that will let you have a table of contents from a selected portion of content, however there are some nifty workarounds available mentioned below you can try it out.

[Add navigation table to wiki page](http://www.n8d.at/blog/enhance-wiki-page-layout-by-adding-a-navgational-table-of-contents/)

[SP 2010 workaround, should be valid for 2013](http://junestime.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/add-table-of-contents-to-a-wiki-page-in-sharepoint-2010/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simpler solution that requires no deployment at all: just add a UserCustomAction with a ScriptLink by running the following in the browser developer tools console:

```
var sp = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var uca = sp.get_web().get_userCustomActions().add();
uca.set_name('AddWikiPageToC'); 
uca.set_location('ScriptLink');
uca.set_scriptBlock('{ \
function addWikiToC() {\
    var contentContainer = $(\'#contentBox div.edit-mode-border\'), \
        tocContainer = $(\'.ewiki-slink\');\
\
    tocContainer.append(\'<div id="pageTOC" style="margin-top:1.1em; width:250px;"><strong>Table of Contents</strong><div id="pageTOC-UL"></div></div>\');\
\
    contentContainer.find(\':header\')\
                    .each(function () {\
                        $(\'#pageTOC-UL\').append(\'<div style="padding-left:\'+this.tagName.replace(/h/ig,\'\')+\'em"><a onclick="javascript:$(\\\'#s4-workspace\\\').animate({scrollTop: \'+($(this).offset().top-80)+\'}, 1000)">\'+$(this).text()+\'</a></div>\');\
                    });\
}\
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(\'addWikiToC\')\
}'); 
uca.update(); 
sp.executeQueryAsync();
```

In this rudimentary form it only works on all enterprise wiki pages with the social rating box and builds a sequence of indented `div` elements below it, but it's very easy improve by changing selectors for `contentContainer` and styles for entries below `pageTOC-UL`.