# Table of Contents for all wiki pages?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, content

I know that I'm supposed to search for data in a Wiki but I would like to structure the data in some kind of tree. Is this possible?

Right now I just have pages that do not really belong to anything so to get there I need to search and when doing that I might miss it.

EDIT : Lets clear this up, Im not looking for a Table of Content on one page, Im looking for a Table of Content of all wiki pages. So when I go to the main Wiki page I will find the Table Of Content there, clicking a content link will take me to the proper wiki page.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your Site Contents and find the document library 'Pages' and/or 'SitePages' that's where all of your wiki pages will be located.  You can insert that on your Home page and create a view on that document library and use it as a 'Table of Contents'.  It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's completely OOTB and no coding necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while trying to find the same answer a while ago. [Link to post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86562/sharepoint-wiki-table-of-contents). For convenience purposes here are links posted from the post.

[Add navigation table to wiki page](http://www.n8d.at/blog/enhance-wiki-page-layout-by-adding-a-navgational-table-of-contents/)
[SP 2010 workaround, should be valid for 2013](http://junestime.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/add-table-of-contents-to-a-wiki-page-in-sharepoint-2010/comment-page-1/)

Both claim to be valid for 2013.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not what I meant, look at the edit.

Comment: I gotcha now. Sorry for the poor answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I updated my [Add navigation table to wiki page](http://www.n8d.at/blog/enhance-wiki-page-layout-by-adding-a-navgational-table-of-contents/) solution to support multiple levels and SharePoint 2013.

The new solution is a configurable jquery plugin and is documented in the blog post [Revised: Table of Contents for Wiki Pages](http://www.n8d.at/blog/revised-table-of-contents-for-wiki-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

The BlueBridge Wiki Extensions provide a navigation webpart to add on selected wiki pages (or on all, using the auto webpart functionality), a possibility to add chapter names and numbers to each wiki page and a feature to add a tree below the quicklaunch navigation for the entire wiki pages library.